# Qt equivalent of timeGetTime()

Tags: qt, time, unsigned-integer, dword

Is there in the QT libraries an equivalent of the `timeGetTime()` function of the `Windows.h` header? I wish my code was as platform-independent as possible. I know the `<chrono>` header exists, but I would like something that returns the value in `DWORD`

```
float AudioThread::br()
{
    QTime tmp(0,0);
    DWORD time = tmp.msecsSinceStartOfDay();
    QWORD pos = BASS_StreamGetFilePosition(chan, BASS_FILEPOS_CURRENT);
        if (pos != lastpos) {
          lasttime = time;
          lastpos = pos;
        }
    }
    qDebug() << tmp.msecsSinceStartOfDay() << pos;
    return 8.0 * (pos - lastpos) / (time - lasttime);
}
```

Inserting this code into a `QTimer`, `tmp.msecsSinceStartOfDay()` always returns `0`

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might use `QTime::msecsSinceStartOfDay() `, but in contrast to `timeGetTime()` it returns the number of milliseconds since the midnight, and not from when Windows started.

Comment: With <chrono> you can extract `.time_since_epoch().count()` from `Clock::now()`, but still that may not fit `DWORD` and will not be from windows start.

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to guess, what you really want.
Looking at your code, you set tmp to 0, afterwards you calculate the difference of tmp(which is still at 0) with 0 (the start of the day) which makes your variable time = 0-0 = 0. Perfectly correct but not what you want.
If you want to know, what the current time is, you could use

```
QTime tm = QTime::currentTime();
DWORD dtime = tm.msecsSinceStartOfDay();
```

BTW: I would not use a variable named `time` as this might create confusion with the `time()` library function. I have seen very strange behaviour after using a variable named 'time'.